# Woocommerce & Opayo Plugin (Reference Field in SagePay)

Tags: woocommerce, customization, opayo

We are thinking of using the Opayo Plugin as our new Payment Gateway on our Woocommerce websites. We are using Opayo Form (not Opayo Direct), I have been testing it and it works great if it wasn't for Accounts that would really like the Reference field to display "Order Number - Last Name" (eg. 654321 - Smith). At the moment it stands empty and it would make their work much easier if they could see those at a glance. (see pic below).

[image]

I have tried this hook unsuccessfully in function.php, there is a bit of guessing on my part as the documentation is scarce.

```
    add_filter( 'opayo_direct_custom_field_vendordata', 'my_opayo_direct_custom_field_vendordata', 10, 2 );
    function my_opayo_direct_custom_field_vendordata ( $vendor_data, $order ) {
      $reference = $order->get_order_number() . '-' . $order->get_billing_last_name();
      if ( ! empty($reference) ) {
        $vendor_data['Reference'] = $reference;
    }
    return $vendor_data;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that you typed *'Reference'* instead of *'reference'*. This could be the problem. If it doesn't solve your problem try checking this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66335761/10447197

Comment: @VincenzoDiGaetano I did try both spelling with no luck

Comment: Just to be clear there are two payment options, I am looking for the Opayo Form solution, NOT Opayo Direct

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to help you. You should check in the plugin documentation or directly in the code. Otherwise contact plugin support.